# Find element that has both children and string in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My source is:

```
<content>
  <caption>text 1</caption>
  <element1>Notepad is a basic text-editing program and it's most commonly used to view or edit text files. A text <bold>file</bold> is a <a>file</a> type typically identified by the .txt file name extension.</element1>
  <section1>
     <element2>Notepad is a basic text-editing program and it's most commonly used to view or edit text files. A text file is a file type typically identified by the .txt file name extension.</element2>
   </section1>
 </content>
```

I am trying to extract and create unique ID for the elements (it may be any element) which has both child (character elements) and text, and also the elements which has only text. The `<bold>` and `<a>` elements should not be seperated.

```
  <caption id="id1">Text 1</caption>
  <element1 id="id2">Notepad is a basic text-editing program and it's most commonly used to view or edit text files. A text <bold>file</bold> is a <a>file</a> type typically identified by the .txt file name extension.</element1>
  <element2 id="id3">Notepad....</element2>
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Where is <content> and <section1> in your output format? Do you want to skip them?

Comment: Yes I would like to extract only the element has string/string + child(Character) elements.. The element that has only children but no PCDATA need not be considered.

Comment: The **caption** and **element2** elements in your example has no child elements, but still is given an id attribute. This seems to contradict where you say you want to create IDs from elements which has both child and text. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Its for both elements whcih has child and text. And also for the elements which has only text. So that I have given an ID for caption and element2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure whether you want to preserve the hierarchy or whether you want to output a flat list of those elements you have described; the following simply extracts the described elements as a flat list (though preserving their content), the `id`s are generated by the XSLT processor:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and text()[normalize-space()]] | *[* and text()[normalize-space()]]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="id" select="generate-id()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="copy"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input sample, Saxon 9 outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<caption id="d1e2">text 1</caption>
<element1 id="d1e4">Notepad is a basic text-editing program and it's most commonly used to view or edit text files. A text <bold>file</bold> is a <a>file</a> type typically identified by the .txt file name extension.</element1>
<element2 id="d1e13">Notepad is a basic text-editing program and it's most commonly used to view or edit text files. A text file is a file type typically identified by the .txt file name extension.</element2>
```

Comment: Hi @Martin, Thank you for code. Actually the child element should be anything not only bold or a. How that could be handled?

Comment: Please explain in more details how to identify the elements that need an `id` attribute and those that don't need one. I don't see a difference between the `bold` or `a` elements and the `caption` elements (both with pure text content), besides distinguishing them by name.

Comment: Hi @Martin. Yes you are correct. But in this case, the parent element of caption doesn’t have the PCDATA, hence it contains only child element. These elements could be removed and the id should be included in child ie `<caption>`. But in `<bold>` and `<a>` elements have the parent element which has the PCDATA (string) so in the parent element the id could be included not in children.

Comment: Its little confusing I think

Comment: So once a parent or ancestor element has been transformed to get an `id` attribute value the child and descendant elements like the `bold` or `a` elements can simply be copied, without needing to look for elements to get `id`s? Is that correct?